# Remove underline from a string in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, string, underline, charsequence

I'm getting text input from an editText and setting it as a notification .setTitle, but when it shows in the notification, it shows up with an underline on certain words. I had no idea why, but when I went to test it, the android keyboard puts underlines under words it has auto completed. So, what would be the best method to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
getText().toString()
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504433/how-to-remove-the-underline-from-the-edittext-field-in-android)

Comment: Hmm... I guess I must be using char sequence. Can anyone confirm that a char sequence will include underlines?

Comment: String is implementation of Charsequence