# how to remove EditText's underline in android

Tags: android

how to remove these two lines,thank you!
you see the black underline and the green underline below the "morning"
[image]

I saw some solution: android:background="@null"
it remove the green underline, but the green underline still in there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831577/remove-additional-underline-in-edittext

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: @Seife ops the green underline gone, but the black underline still in there

Comment: @ADM I fixed the problem, the answer of the guy@Sumit Jain,give me the solution, thank's both of you

Comment: @Seife I got the solution, you ways+android:inputType="textVisiblePassword", and it works well

Comment: It would be a greae idea to attach the layout, to better understand, what those lines are

Comment: @RusArtM thanks for you hinting,could you give me some reference materials about this, I want to study it, thank you very much

Comment: @jasa But I still can't see what your layout made of. Please include your layout xml

Comment: @RusArtM Sorry bro, I think I have misunderstanded your idea, now I know it, the view in my layout, is a linearlayout includes just only one EditText, that's it, But I got it, next time when I post questions, I will attach my layout, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @jasa If you havn't solved your problem you can edit your post and add the layout code. Was the value in your example set programattically or was it typed manually? Coud it be spanned text? All this would be clear with a small code example.

Comment: @RusArtM thank you very much, I got the answer, in EditText view I added two attrs: android:background="@android:color/transparent", android:inputType="textVisiblePassword",                                                                    with these two attrs, I have solved the problem that I asked.